# ngResource, pass params into transformRequest function

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, ngresource

Given:

```
 Users = $resource apiUrl+"/v1/users/?offset=:offset&limit=:limit&format=json", {}, 
     getNext: 
       method: 'GET'

 Users.getNext { offset:20, limit:20 }, (data)->
     console.log "got some data"
```

Instead of explicitly passing `offset` and `limit`, I'd like to pass current set and in `transformRequest` function extract `limit` and `offset` and set those parameters for the http call. How can I do it?
Doing something like that not working:

```
 Users = $resource apiUrl+"/v1/users/?offset=:offset&limit=:limit&format=json", {}, 
     getNext: 
       transformRequest: transformReq(data)

transformReq = (data)->
   console.log "data == "+data
```

and even this doesn't:

```
transformReq = (data)-> 
   [
       (data) ->
           console.log "data =="+data     # undefined   
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

it will intercept the transformReq when use the POST method, I am looking for the way the deal with the req too.